# How I can add a legend in a mapbox map in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl

I have seen examples in HTML but I dont know how to do it in react.
I had tried this but it doesnt work

map.mapboxgl.legendControl({ position: 'topright' }).addLegend('**My walk from the White House to the hill!**').addTo(map);